# Why am I receiving this MailApp error when I run my GAS function?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, gmail

To my understanding from the documentation and various examples I've seen, MailApp options/attachment should be compatible with an array of Blobs. I've used various bits of code I found here and other places to cobble together something that would search a specific folder and it's subfolders while avoiding others folders on my Drive (that have different files sharing the same file names) for a dynamic list of PDF file names pulled from a Sheet. I'm scraping the bottom of my mental barrel for ideas as to what could be causing this and how to fix it. Hopefully somebody here can give me some guidance.

Snippet of code in question:

```
  var c = sheet.getRange(6,2,lastValue.length-5,1)
  var fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var values = c.getValues();
  var getFiles = function getFiles(folder) {
    var folders = folder.getFolders();
    while(folders.hasNext()) {
      var fol = folders.next();
      getFiles(fol);
    }
    var files = folder.getFiles();
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var f = files.next();
        for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
          for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {                  
            values[i][j] = values[i][j] +".pdf" == f.getName() ? (f.getBlob()) : values[i][j];        
         }       
       } 
    }
  }
  (fldr);
  var att=[values.join()]
  MailApp.sendEmail(emails,emailSubject,emailBody,{attachments: att});
```

[Error message in Logger:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RM2bH.png)

['att' variable in Logger:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIHM6.png)

The code runs perfect when I restrict it to a single Blob using [0] in my variable array. I've tried various array layouts; no array Blob,Blob normal array [Blob,Blob] nested arrays [[Blob],[Blob]]. I've tried getAs(attachments+'.PDF') instead of getBlob, which had the same results. I've done various testing of all of the above using GmailApp instead of MailApp.

Comment: att looks wrong it should be an array of files, not file names or urls of files but actual objects of Class File

Comment: It's wierd to have joined a 2d array.  I've never tried it myself but I don't think it's a good idea.

Comment: what is column 2 of sh

Comment: Hi Cooper, thank you for the response. I'm not so great with array layouts so I wasn't quite sure how to change the 'values' variable output [[Blob], [Blob]] from an array of arrays into a single array output other than joining them. I had assumed that might be the issue keeping this from working, but I couldn't find another way to do it.

Comment: Try - [Array.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

Comment: But then I think you will just have an array of strings not files

Comment: B6:B hold the file names.

Comment: Ah file names.  Well that's a problem because att needs to be an array of files not filenames

Comment: Array.flat(Infinity) worked! Thank you so much Cooper. The file names get replaced by the blobs each time a match is found in a subfolder. The issue was join() just like you thought.

Comment: It's unfortunate that you chose to collect file names rather than id's.  If you collect id's then you could create an array of files easily with a forEach or reduce

Comment: I'm new to interactions on stackoverflow, so I'm not sure of the etiquette, but if you would like to post your comment as an Answer I'd love to accept it in case anybody else runs into this particular type of problem.

Comment: `let att = idsA.map(id  => DriveApp.getFileById(id));`